# Cannot get .htaccess file rewrite to work using a local dev server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, xampp

I cannot get my .htaccess file to rewrite the URLs.  Here is what I have made sure of:

- httpd.conf file has `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` uncommented.
- httpd.conf file under `<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">` has `AllowOverride All`.
- phpinfo() has `mod_rewrite` is under Loaded Modules.

I am currently using XAMPP.

My main directory is `C:\xampp\htdocs\test`.

Inside the `test` folder I have a basic `index.php` file and the `.htaccess` file.

Inside the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$\ http://google.com [L]

#RewriteRule ^(.*)$\ index.php/$1 [L]
#RewriteBase /test/
```

- The `.htaccess` file is being accessed because when I throw garbage in the file I get a `500 error` when I visit my `index.php` page.
- The bottom two commented rules are what I intend on using, but right now just redirecting to google will let me know if it works.  I have tried it using the commented rules, but with no luck.
- The `.htaccess` rules do work on my web server.

When I access my `index.php` page, I am not redirected.  It just loads the page normally.

I have spent 4+ hours searching for a solution, but have not had any luck.  I have tried both XAMPP and EasyPHP, but same issue for both.

If anyone has any thoughts or suggestions at all, I would very much appreciate it.

**Edit:**

Here are the error logs when I start Apache after I restart my PC:

```
[Thu Jul 31 18:05:22.365119 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 6380:tid 384] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Jul 31 18:05:22.396117 2014] [core:warn] [pid 6380:tid 384] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Thu Jul 31 18:05:22.512122 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 6380:tid 384] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Jul 31 18:05:22.851147 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6380:tid 384] AH00455: Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1g PHP/5.5.11 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Jul 31 18:05:22.851147 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6380:tid 384] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 16 2014 12:13:13
[Thu Jul 31 18:05:22.851147 2014] [core:notice] [pid 6380:tid 384] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Thu Jul 31 18:05:22.853142 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6380:tid 384] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 3936
[Thu Jul 31 18:05:23.241170 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 3936:tid 416] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Jul 31 18:05:23.388142 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 3936:tid 416] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Jul 31 18:05:23.423146 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3936:tid 416] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Answer (score 0):

That `\` in your pattern is screwing everything up. What's actually happening is the `\` is *escaping the space* which makes mod_rewrite think the pattern *and* target are both the pattern, and the `[L]` flag is the target. Apache directives and parameters are separated by spaces, so when you escape the space, it makes apache thing the entire thing is a single parameter.

What you have:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$\ http://google.com [L]
|directive| | pattern               | | target |
```

So get rid of the `\`"

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://google.com [L]
```

So that the directive is `RewriteRule`, the pattern is `^(.*)$`, the target is `http://google.com` and the flags are `[L]`.

Comment: You're right that it shouldn't be in there, not sure how I got that.  But even after changing it I still have the same issue.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Absolutely nothing :/

Comment: Actually there were some errors, not sure if relevant or not.  They weren't occuring when I try to access the page, only when Apache starts (after I restarted my PC).  I posted them as an edit to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Two other reasons I can think of:

1. your .htaccess file is actually a .txt file, i.e. ".htaccess.txt", but the ".txt" file extension is hidden in the file explorer. (See "Type of file:" field in file's properties to check actual file extension)
2. your .htaccess file don't have permission to be read by the server.

Remark: I have checked your syntax should work.

Comment: 1. I checked, and the file type is HTACCESS, not txt.

2. The server can definitely access it, because when I throw junk characters in the file, I get a `500 error`.

Comment: Have you checked no other .conf files' "AllowOverride None" override your setting?  (They are included by e.g. ``Include path/to/*.conf'' inside the main httpd.conf file)

Comment: Yeah, every included .conf file has their `AllowOverride`'s set to `All`.